# I am trying to make a site with login register username password system on godaddy

Tags: html, authentication

I am trying to make a site with login  , register,  username, password system on godaddy. But i cant figure out how to  do so? The customer support says that i can only write code in html , i don't get it,  pleases help me.

Comment: I'd suggest finding someone to hire or taking classes online to learn about web development. There are a lot of great sites to learn from. However, this is not a question with a simple answer.

Comment: i bought a web development tool, i have to  design the site thru it... it shows a site wide code option . there r two columns . head and body. i dont know which code to put where